# How to delete nodejs and npm from my Ubuntu device?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to fully delete the nodejs and npm from my Ubuntu device.
I ran these commands but still nodejs and npm in my device.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

The output in terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nodejs' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
```

So, after that when I open the terminal to check the version of the node and npm, I ran these commands:

```
>>> node -v
>>> npm -v
```

and still print to me the version of it, which is:

node: v10.15.2

npm: 6.4.1

What is the problem here, is my command wrong?

Comment: run `which node` & `which npm`, it will show paths where its located.

Comment: how did you install the packages? apt uninstalls packages installed with the relevant manager (in this case, they were not installed with apt *Package 'nodejs' is not installed, so not removed*)

Comment: Yes! i did it.
The output is:
/home/oses/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.2/bin/node
What shall I do here?
@bogdanoff

Comment: I installed it by NVM, I saw google search "How to install nodejs in Ubuntu" @mrmcwolf

Comment: I think `nvm uninstall node` will uninstall it. see  [docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#intro)

Comment: In that case, use `nvm` to uninstall the packages `nvm uninstall ...` Or simply uninstall nvm